# Jquery Autocomplete working on local but not on production

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm banging my head off of the keyboard here trying to figure this out.

I have a website that is using the jquery UI autocomplete functionality on a single field on the search form. Super simple, just pulling a list from an array, no server-side stuff happening at all. The code is basically pulled directly from the Jquery UI examples page (https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

On my local development environment, which is using Laravel on Homestead, it works flawlessly. But on the server (with identical code) it's not working at all. There are no errors inside the console, so it's nearly impossible to tell what is going wrong here. I have other sites on this same server that use autocomplete with no issues, which makes it even stranger.

Here is the code:

For the form field

```
<label for="subdivisons">Subdivision</label>
<input type="text" id="subdivisons" name="subdivision" class="form-control" value="{{ old('subdivision') }}" placeholder="Choose a subdivision">
```

And this is the jquery function from the footer:

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js') }}"></script>

<script>
$( function() {
  var available_subdivisions = [
    "CAPE HAZE WINDWARD",
    "CLUBHOUSE",
    "EAGLES PRESERVE SUBDIVISION",
    "FIDDLERS GREEN",
    "FIDDLERS GREEN NATURE TRAIL",
    "FIDDLERS GREEN RIVERVIEW",
    "FIDDLERS GREEN TALL PINES",
    "LEMON TREE",
    "OAKLAND HILLS SEC",
    "PINEHURST",
    "PORT CHARLOTTE SUBS",
    "PRESERVE AT WINDWARD PH1",
    "RIVERHOUSE",
    "ROTONDA BROADMOOR",
    "ROTONDA HEIGHTS",
    "ROTONDA LAKES",
    "ROTONDA RIVER CONDO",
    "ROTONDA SHORES",
    "ROTONDA WEST BROADMOOR",
    "ROTONDA WEST LONG MEADOW",
    "ROTONDA WEST OAKLAND HILL",
    "ROTONDA WEST OAKLAND HILLS",
    "ROTONDA WEST PEBBLE BEACH",
    "ROTONDA WEST PINE VALLEY",
    "ROTONDA WEST PINEHURST",
    "ROTONDA WEST WHITE MARSH",
    "SOUTH GULF COVE",
    "SUNSET VILLAGE AT ROTONDA WEST",
    "TOWNHOMES AT CAPE HAZE"
  ];
$( "#subdivisons" ).autocomplete({
    source: available_subdivisions
  });
});
</script>
```

Again, this is basically the exact same thing that is used on the jquery autocomplete examples page, and it works perfectly on my local dev server. No console errors. I checked all src elements to make sure they were linked properly. And again, I'm using Autocomplete on several other websites that are hosted on this server. The only difference is that they are using a remote data source rather than pulling from an array, but I wouldn't think that would be an issue. I just can't seem to figure this one out.

Thanks!

Comment: might be the reason the assets folder you are using does not have the sufficient rights

Comment: Did you checked the console? Did you get any errors? Are the js files accesible?

Comment: can you share the production url ?

Comment: ok is it possible to share the url where you have embedded it live

Comment: also make sure it isnt a css issue, which is hiding the dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my available_subdivisions array was being included inside of the main layout blade view as well as in the extended view. Once I removed it from the extended view it functions perfectly as it should. Stupid mistake on my part.